# Не запускается скрипт через passthru

Tags: php

Имеется python скрипт glyph-tower.py.

Я запускаю его через терминал на сервере - вывод нормальный, все верно.

```
python3.6 glyph-tower.py -i="dodge3896934473/dodge3896934473_parsed"
```

Запускаю через

```
<?php passthru('python3.6 glyph-tower.py -i="dodge3896934473/dodge3896934473_parsed"') ?>
```

В ответ ничего..
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: попробуй в пускаче прописать полный путь к бинарнику python3.6

Comment: обычный скрипт с хеллоу ворлдом запускается на ура без указания полного пути

Comment: 1. passthru возвращает значение, а не выводит его
2. в терминале через <?php явно не запускаются скрипты
Постараюсь наванговать, что вам нужно этот код
<?php echo passthru('python3.6 glyph-tower.py -i="dodge3896934473/dodge3896934473_parsed"') ?>

Comment: все равно не работает